# YAML helm chart how to escape & sign

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I have a helm chart in yaml like this:

```
env:
   - name: EmailHeader
     value: {{ .Values.npsweb.email.support.header | quote }}
```

and in my Values file, I have like this:

```
npsweb:
   email:
      support:
         header: &lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;img src='https://nps.dev.nuancepowershare.com/smr/images/weblogo.png' alt='SMR LOGO' /&gt;&lt;hr /&gt;
```

But it says that `Anchor lt;html><body><img is never used`. I tried putting double quote around it, but it still didn't get picked up.

What is the problem here and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly quote the string.  There are a couple of ways to do this, so pick whichever makes sense:

```yaml
header-with-single-quotes: '&lt;.../&gt;'
header-with-double-quotes: "&lt;.../&gt;"
header-as-block-scalar: |-
  &lt;html&gt;...&lt;/html&gt;
header-as-block-scalar-with-whitespace: |-
  &lt;html&gt;
    &lt;body&gt;
      ...
    &lt;/body&gt;
  &lt;/html&gt;
```

All of these forms are the same, except that the last one will include embedded newlines and spaces.  (Since your value includes single quotes, the single-quoted form will be a little less convenient.)  You could also consider [storing the HTML content in a file](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/) and reading it in with `.Files.Get` (though Helm doesn't include a template function for escaping HTML).

What's wrong with your existing `values.yaml` file?  YAML has the notion of an [anchor](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2785586); you can give a part of a document a label like this, and reference it from elsewhere in the document.  The '&' character at the beginning of the value marks an anchor, and the text up to the first space is the name of the anchor.

Not so much in Kubernetes, but in Docker Compose you'll somewhat routinely see this for reusable blocks of environment variables:

```yaml
# (This is a Docker Compose file, not Kubernetes, as a YAML example)
version: '3.8'
x-environment: &environment # <-- anchor
  DB_HOST: db
services:
  db: { image: postgres }
  application:
    build: .
    environment: *environment # <-- reference to anchor
  worker:
    build: .
    command: ./worker
    environment: *environment # <-- same reference to anchor
```